# Why does this WCF Proxy code work?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, idisposable

While debugging in an app, I found the following code.  It's obviously wrong, but for some strange reason it works, and I can't seem to understand why.  It would seem to me that the Proxy would be disposed as soon as it was created, yet calling methods on this proxy work correctly to connect to the WCF service.

Can anyone explain why this code doesn't blow up?

```
private static IMyService _proxy = null;
private static IMyService Proxy
{
  get
  {
    if (_proxy == null)
    {
      using (_proxy as IDisposable)
      {
        ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory = 
             new ChannelFactory<IMyService>("MyService");
        _proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
      }
    }
    return _proxy;
  }
}
```

Comment: the compiler might make a temporary variable.

Comment: @DanielA.White - That's what I was thinking.. perhaps the As creates a copy of the reference (which in this case is null anyways?)

Comment: yep thats it. since its not really disposing on _proxy.

Comment: @DanielA.White - it's a good theory, but are you certain?

Comment: its entirely compiler specific.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - That was another theory I had... Can anyone support this? (ildism maybe?)

Comment: [Dispose only called on non-null objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522822/c-sharp-using-statement-with-a-null-object)?

Comment: There is more: the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) actually says `within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.` The compiler should not let the assignment pass, and I have no idea why it does. *Oh yes, I have, it's not the "same" object. `foo as IDisposable` is not the same thing as `foo`.*

Comment: @StuartLC - Yes, I'm aware of that.. but the variable is not null when the method ends.  The question is, is this because a null check is done before the scope is executed only?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - probably because the object is declared outside of the using block.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch no the null check happens in the finally.

Comment: which version of C#, .Net etc?

Comment: @AK_ - This code is quite old, and has been in the code base since at least VS2008, we're currently using VS2013, but targeting .net 4.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the compiler clearly creates a copy in the `using(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really is interesting!.

It is apparent that combination of the use of an *existing* variable in the `using()` statement *and* the reassignment of the original within the block, results in a new reference which is passed to `Dispose()`, and not the existing `_proxy`, as per the IL below.

In fact, LinqPad issues a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhdyhfk6(v=vs.90).aspx) to this effect:

> Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'variable' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

However this behaviour does *not* appear to require a cast to `as IDisposable`, nor does the `static` seem to have any effect.

Disassembling the following code to IL in LINQPad:

```
IMyService _proxy = null;
if (_proxy == null)
{
   using (_proxy)
   {
      _proxy = new SomeService();
   }
}
```

Yields

```
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0004:  ldnull      
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  ceq         
IL_000A:  stloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_000B:  ldloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_000C:  brtrue.s    IL_002D
IL_000E:  nop         
** IL_000F:  ldloc.0     // _proxy
** IL_0010:  stloc.2     // CS$3$0001
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeService..ctor
IL_0017:  stloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0018:  nop         
IL_0019:  leave.s     IL_002B
$IL_001B:  ldloc.2     // CS$3$0001
$IL_001C:  ldnull      
$IL_001D:  ceq         
IL_001F:  stloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_0020:  ldloc.1     // CS$4$0000
$IL_0021:  brtrue.s    IL_002A
** IL_0023:  ldloc.2     // CS$3$0001
IL_0024:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_0029:  nop         
IL_002A:  endfinally  
IL_002B:  nop
```

As can be seen (by the **'s), that a new loc 2 is created, and it is this reference which is passed to `Dispose()`. But prior to this is a check for null ($), which bypasses the `Dispose` in any event.

Contrast this with the explicit `try-finally`:

```
 if (_proxy == null)
 {
    try
    {
       _proxy = new SomeService();
    }
    finally
    {
       _proxy.Dispose();
    }
 }

IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0004:  ldnull      
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  ceq         
IL_000A:  stloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_000B:  ldloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_000C:  brtrue.s    IL_0025
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  nop         
IL_0010:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeService..ctor
IL_0015:  stloc.0     // _proxy
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  leave.s     IL_0023
IL_0019:  nop         
** IL_001A:  ldloc.0     // _proxy
IL_001B:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_0020:  nop         
IL_0021:  nop         
IL_0022:  endfinally  
IL_0023:  nop
```

Where it can be clearly seen that it is the `"original" _proxy` which is Disposed, without the extra null check done in the `using()`, confirming [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Needless to say this code is evil:

- `_proxy` will never be `Disposed`, viz the `using` is redundant.
- [It relies on passing null to `using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522822/c-sharp-using-statement-with-a-null-object) not failing.
- Because `_proxy` is defined *prior* to the `using`, it can be reassigned within the block, unlike variables [declared IN the using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28VS.71%29.aspx) statement - e.g. `using (var _proxy = ...)` would be `read-only`, and attempting to mutate such a variable would result in a compile time error anyway.
- The merits of static singleton channels aside, the lazy initialization of `_proxy` is also not thread-safe (e.g. no double-check lock), and could be simplified with a `private static readonly Lazy<IMyService>(() => ...)` and a simple getter.

Comment: Thanks for the disassembly and analysis.  It seems clear that the `as IDisposable` is creating a new reference, and in fact removing it results in a compiler error.  I'm guessing the `as IDisposable` was added to make it compile.  Yes, the code is evil, and I am rewriting it.  But, I always like to understand why code functions the way it does.

Comment: The `_proxy As IDisposable` is probably just needed because `IMyService` doesn't implement `IDisposable` whereas another interface implemented by `Proxy` does, hence the compiler error. However, in the above, if `IMyService` directly implements `IDisposable`, the additional IL var is still created for disposal even without a cast. Thanks for sharing this code - it almost looks right at first glance - great for interviewee questions ;). I'm guessing that the compiler ideally should have `temporarily` made `_proxy` readonly in the using `block`, but can't support this.

Answer (score 2):

That code works because of:

```
using (_proxy as IDisposable)
```

The expression `_proxy as IDisposable` is not `_proxy`, and that explains why `_proxy` can be assigned to within the `using` block without the C# compiler complaining in any way.

In addition, even if `_proxy` is subsequently set to a non-`null` disposable instance, the original value as "seen" by the `using` block (`_proxy as IDisposable`) will still be `null` (there are no references involved in this context).

Therefore, nothing is disposed of, a new proxy is created and cached, and that code succeeds.

I'm still wondering about the potential reasons why one would like to write such a `using` statement, however.

Comment: Do you have any references to the fact that casting a variable creates a new reference?

Comment: This question mentions reference conversions point to the same reference, but user-defined conversions do not, the question is, what type is this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064297/does-casting-an-object-in-c-sharp-always-return-a-reference-to-the-intial-object

Comment: @Erik, that actually a matter of value, not reference. `_proxy as IDisposable` returns the *value* `null`, and that value will remain `null` even if `_proxy` subsequently changes.

Comment: Well, the code was obviously not well written.  It obviously was not intended to function this way.  It's old code, in an old windows forms app.  I'm fixing it, but I was simply confused as to why it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently you can have null as the input to a using scope:

```
using (null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hamster");
}
```

What happens is that `_proxy` is null and therefore `_proxy as IDisposable` is also null which makes the using scope redundant, no `Dispose` will be called (or attempted). The code is equivalent to this:

```
if (_proxy == null)
{
    ChannelFactory<IBasketService> factory =
            new ChannelFactory<IBasketService>("MyService");
    _proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
}
return _proxy;
```

It doesn't matter that `_proxy` is assigned to while inside the scope, `Dispose` would be "invoked" on the original **copied** value (which is null).

---

Here's a simple snippet that reproduces the issue. The "Disposed" message will *not* be written to console.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static DisposableScope _proxy = null;
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (_proxy)
        {
            _proxy = new DisposableScope();
        }
    }
}

public class DisposableScope : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }
}
```